I have SVG file contain a normal rectangle
I have SVG file containing a normal rectangle
<polygon id="REC1" class="cls-1" points="227.02 .25 141.98 .25 141.98 385 227.02 385 227.02 .25"/>

my question is how to change the size of this rec1 to the new size by enter one width and replace the points to the new size?
I'm using python.

Is your problem with parsing SVG files in Python, or how to do the math to get the new points?

how to do the math to get the new points?

This sounds like high school geometry. If you need help with it, [math.se] is a better place to ask.

Use a scale/translate transform and don't edit the points at all.

I highly recommend to convert the <polygon>  to a proper <rect> like <rect x="141.98" y="0.25" width="85.04" height="384.75"/>. All you need would be method like getBBox() (JS) to retrieve the current x,y, width and height values. Otherwise, just get the min and max values for all x and y values: polygons rely on absolute pairs of x/y values. x=xMin; y=yMin; width=xMax-xMin; height=yMax-yMin.

@RobertLongson can you explain it

new scale in x = new width / old width etc.
